# Derivation of the efficient frontier set (markowitz problem)

Tags: optimization, portfolio-optimization, markowitz

I would like to find a Derivation of the efficient frontier set for the markowitz problem:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this constraint minimization problem, first form the Lagrangian Function
\begin{align}
L(w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=w'\Sigma w + \lambda_1(w'\boldsymbol{\mu}-m) + \lambda_2 (w'\boldsymbol{1}-1).
\end{align}

The first order conditions for a minimum are then given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta L(w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{\delta w}&=2 \Sigma w + \lambda_1 \boldsymbol{\mu} + \lambda_2 \boldsymbol{1}=\boldsymbol{0} \\
\frac{\delta L(w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{\lambda_1}&=w'\boldsymbol{\mu}-m=0 \\
\frac{\delta L(w,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{\lambda_2}&=w'\boldsymbol{1}-1=0.
\end{align}

This system of linear equations using matrix algebra can be represented as
\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
2\Sigma & \boldsymbol{\mu} & \boldsymbol{1} \\
\boldsymbol{\mu}' & 0 & 0 \\
\boldsymbol{1}' & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
w  \\
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{0}  \\
m \\
1
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
or 
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{b},
\end{align}
where

\begin{align}
 \boldsymbol{A}:=\begin{bmatrix} 
2\Sigma & \boldsymbol{\mu} & \boldsymbol{1} \\
\boldsymbol{\mu}' & 0 & 0 \\
\boldsymbol{1}' & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},
\boldsymbol{z}:=
 \begin{bmatrix} 
w  \\
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 
\end{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{b}:=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\boldsymbol{0}  \\
m \\
1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
The solution for $\boldsymbol{z}$ is then given by (A has full rank and is thus invertible)

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{z}=\boldsymbol{A}^{-1} \boldsymbol{b}
\end{align}

The first element of $\boldsymbol{z}$ gives you the set of efficient portfolios varying m.

Comment: You might add that one can analytically block invert $A$. This means that if all you really want is the first element of $z$, then you can save yourself some calculations.